# Efficient way to compare [u8] arrays and find index of the first not equal item

Tags: rust

I need to compare two arrays that consist of u8 elements and find an index of the first, not an equal element. Something similar to this one https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#mismatch(short%5B%5D,int,int,short%5B%5D,int,int)
Could you suggest the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combination of `zip` and `position` with iterators would be `O(n)`:

```rust
fn find_first_neq_index(a1: &[u8], a2: &[u8]) -> Option<usize> {
    a1.iter().zip(a2.iter()).position(|(a, b)| a != b)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=199db99e9cd001a4062a3dcf432503cc)

Notice that this is valid just in the case of the arrays to be of equal length. If you consider one of them to be a sub-slice of the other this should be enough. If you want to consider that the point of difference then you can expand by checking the lengths.
Another simple solution matching all cases with a simple loop:

```rust
fn find_first_neq_index_different_lengths(a1: &[u8], a2: &[u8]) -> Option<usize> {
    let mut itera = a1.iter();
    let mut iterb = a2.iter();
    let mut i = 0usize;
    loop {
        match (itera.next(), iterb.next()) {
            (None, None) => return None,
            (None, Some(_)) | (Some(_), None) => return Some(i),
            (Some(a), Some(b)) if a != b => return Some(i),
            _ => {
                i += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c7f51911e47077fb61fb5ffe80045e4c)

Comment: more concise:  `a1.iter().zip(a2.iter()).position(|(a, b)| a != b)`  ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f08de574078dbc4d4964b957ec42e08d))

Comment: IMHO it could be better if you mention;  these parameters are slices that allows you to bring `aFromIndex` and `aToIndex`es to the solution naturally.

Comment: Alternatively, [common prefix](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=5c9fb9a151f094b7a5290445b9bc9f0c) optimises well and getting the "first not equal" information from that is trivial (just compare to the length of the slices to know if it fell off the end, otherwise you have the index). The assembly seems a lot cleaner than with `position()`

Comment: Also didn't check with `position()` but with `take_while` and `count`, if you take references to arrays (generic over the size) the compiler will unroll to a pretty ridiculous extent.

Comment: @ÖmerErden, nice!, forgot about position :)

Comment: As a more generic implementation, use `T: Eq` instead of `u8`